# Vehicle tracking by modifying camshift

Tags: opencv

I found this line of code in the openCV sample file for camshift and I am wondering whether is this the line which initiate the circle for tracking the object?

```
int val = cvRound( cvGetReal1D(hist->bins,i)*histimg->height/255 );
```

Also, could the camshift function used for rectangle object instead of faces ?